# Most Compact Way to Count Number of Lines in a File in C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, line-numbers

What's the most compact way to compute the number of lines of a file?
I need this information to create/initialize a matrix data structure.

Later I have to go through the file again and store the information inside a matrix.

**Update:** Based on Dave Gamble's. But why this doesn't compile?
Note that the file could be very large. So I try to avoid using container
to save memory.

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <vector>        
#include <fstream>       
#include <sstream>       
using namespace std;     


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;      
    }

    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);

    FILE *f=fopen(myfile,"rb");
    int c=0,b;
    while ((b=fgetc(f))!=EOF) c+=(b==10)?1:0;
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tell us why it can't compile. Post your compile errors.

Comment: The guess, though, is that you need to `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: FILE *f=fopen(arg_vec[1],"rb"); please.

Comment: fopen takes a filename, not an ifstream.

Comment: also, if you're not using fopen/fgetc/whatever, replace the fseek(...) with fclose(f);

Comment: and as a matter of good practice, I'd hold off creating the ifstream until after the fclose(f); otherwise you're opening the same file twice.

Comment: Why are you fseek()ing?  Why are you not checking whether fopen succeeds?  The fseek is just silly, but failing to check the success of fopen is catastrophic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FILE *f=fopen(filename,"rb");

int c=0,b;while ((b=fgetc(f))!=EOF) c+=(b==10)?1:0;fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
```

Answer in c.
That kind of compact?

Comment: Ew. [Blah blah 15 characters]

Comment: Be grateful I left in the ?1:0. It works fine without. I couldda saved 4 chars there ;)

Comment: `int c=0;while(!fscanf(f,"%*[^\n]%*c"))c++;fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET)`

Comment: That's magical. I bow down to the excellence of using fscanf like that.

Comment: D'oh, apparently my solution fails if the input contains an empty line -- the `%*[^\n]` directive doesn't match any characters in that case, so it will loop infinitely.  There's not an elegant way to fix that without bloating the char count significantly. =/

Comment: I never knew scanf accepted regex parameters... still an amazingly cool trick!

Comment: @Dave: would your solution be able to handle a blank lane? Also, what is the purpose of the fseek? I ran your code without it and it printed the correct line numbers.

Comment: @Hristo yes, blank lines are just fine; we count the literal number of '\n' characters in the file. The fseek is a nicety to rewind to the start of the file, since the OP needs to then proceed through.
Of course, do note that this is all rather tongue-in-cheek; the efficiency of loading individual bytes is generally rather dreadful compared to allocating some memory and reading large blocks from the file... but the OP asked for compactness.

Answer (score 10):

If the reason you need to "go back again" is because you cannot continue without the size, try re-ordering your setup.

That is, read through the file, storing each line in a `std::vector<string>` or something. Then you have the size, along with the lines in the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::fstream file("main.cpp");
    std::vector<std::string> fileData;

    // read in each line
    std::string dummy;
    while (getline(file, dummy))
    {
        fileData.push_back(dummy);
    }

    // and size is available, along with the file
    // being in memory (faster than hard drive)
    size_t fileLines = fileData.size();

    std::cout << "Number of lines: " << fileLines << std::endl;
}
```

---

Here is a solution without the container:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::fstream file("main.cpp");
    size_t fileLines = 0;    

    // read in each line
    std::string dummy;
    while (getline(file, dummy))
    {
        ++fileLines;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of lines: " << fileLines << std::endl;
}
```

Though I doubt that's the most efficient way. The benefit of this method was the ability to store the lines in memory as you went.

Comment: This is the method I was going to suggest, but it's been long enough since I used C++ that I was going to have to actually test it all out before posting. Thanks for saving me the time+1 :D

Comment: I +REALLY+ love when I can tell someone's actually tested the code, by virtue of the fact that the name of the sourcefile is there as input :D:D

Comment: lol, yeah. I had that 'bingo!' moment when I thought, "I need a file to test with....oh duh"

Comment: If we just need to count, std::istream::ignore() should be more efficient than getline.

Answer (score 10):

I think this might do it...

```
std::ifstream file(f);
int n = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n') + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) { system("wc -l plainfile.txt"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of instances of `'\n'`. This works for *nix (\n) and DOS/Windows (\r\n) line endings, but not for old-skool Mac (System 9 or maybe before that), which used just \r. I've never seen a case come up with just \r as line endings, so I wouldn't worry about it unless you know it's going to be an issue.

Edit: If your input is not ASCII, then you could run into encoding problems as well. What's your input look like?

Comment: That might not be cross-platform (I'm just saying).